# while does this simple c++ program to print powers of 2 work when there are so many things wrong with it?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, logic

I wrote some code I wrote to print the powers of 2 up to like 39 or 40 idk but it dm. Anyway, I wrote it and rather than run the code and it not working because of a logic error, i ran the code and found that it works, and then spotted some logic errors showing that the code shouldn't work. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
int k = 1;
while (i < 40)
{
    while (k < i)
    {
        j = j * 2;
        cout << j <<"\n";
        k++;
    }
    i++;
}
}
```

The output of this code is the powers of 2 up to about 2^40.

Why it shouldn't work: the second while loop shouldn't run because k = 1 and i = 1 so (k < i) is false. Also after each time the second while loop is completed, j and k should be reset to 1 in order for the logic to work however I don't resent them.
Can someone please explain why although all these logic errors, the code still works?

Also I tried this in python and got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial values:

```
i=1, k=1, j=1
```

Then we check `i < 40`. True. Then we check `k < i`. False. Then we increment `i`. Now:

```
i=2, k=1, j=1
```

Check `i < 40`. True. Check `k < i`. True. `j=j*2` sets `j=2`. Print `2`. Increment `k`. Check if `k < i`. False. Increment `i`. Now:

```
i=3, k=2, j=2
```

Following this, the inner loop executes at most once for every iteration of the outer loop. `k < i` is true until the `k++` line, and then becomes true again at the `i++` line.

I'm not sure whether I understand why there are nested loops here in the first place. It could be replaced with

```
while (i < 40) {
  j = j * 2;
  count << j << "\n";
  i++
}
```

What was the intention of `k`?

Comment: Oh ok thanks that clears eveything up, I just didnt carry on following the code after seeing that the interior loop doesnt run because I just assumed the code would end and now I also see why the variables dont need updating.

Comment: Also, your implementation is actually much more simple, I dont know why but I just thought of a very bad way of doing it using k as a counter variable.